# Is there some tool to automatically convert css classes to custom prefixed ones?

Tags: html, css

**Tool to append prefix and or suffix to CSS and HTML Simultaneously**

I like to use scripts on codepen, but often the class names are generic, like p, div , label ect...

So I wonder if there is a tool to substitute class names and append a prefix or suffix to BOTH html, CSS and JS simultaneously.

That way if I use the code on my site it won't conflict with my classes or even ID's...

Something the would turn:

```
<div class="a">Hello</div>
```

Into:

```
<div class="my_a">Hello</div>
```

And ***simultaneously***:

```
.a
```

into

```
.my_a
```

This can be done with find and replace, but it's tedious and prone to errors....

Comment: I am not sure this can be done to your css though, What I can suggest is have a `id` to your body tag and then go ahead and change every css of yours into this `#BodyId .a` etc..

Comment: maybe you need to look into sass/less nesting

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this could be done using [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Linux command line :

```
sed 's/class="\([^"]*\)"/class="my_\1"/g' old.html >new.html
sed 's/\.\([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]\+\)/.my_\1/g' old.css >new.css
```

or in any number of good text editors (Geany, Notepad++, ...) :

replace

`class="([^"]*)"` with `class="my_\1"`

and

`\.([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)` with `.my_\1`

Comment: In Notepad++ how can I do this? What do I put into FIND box and then into REPLACE box?

Comment: I haven't used Notepad++ in quite some time, but some googling brought up this page : http://nliautaud.fr/wiki/articles/notepadpp/expreg#utilisation_dans_notepad
It's in French, but basically, you just have to select "Regular expressions" from the radio button under "Search mode".

Comment: Will not work for `class="multiple class names like this"`.

Comment: They say "I had a problem, so I used a regular expression. Now I have two problems." (see [this](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)). It might work for certain cases but not for certain other cases; it depends on the coding convention of the target file.